# How do I insert scanned urls into url table?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am writing a web crawler and I am having some trouble. Here is some pseudo code of what I am trying to do:

```
for every url in url-list {
    urlid = NextURLID;

    Insert urlid and url to their respective columns URL table

    NextURLID++;
}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
void startCrawl() {
        int NextURLID = 0;
        int NextURLIDScanned = 0;

        try
        {
            openConnection(); //Open the database
        }
        catch (SQLException | IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String url = "http://jsoup.org";
        print("Fetching %s...", url);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");

        for (Element link : links) {
            urlID = NextURLID;

            //Code to insert (urlid, url)  to the URL table

            NextURLID++;

        }
}
```

As you can see I do not have the code to insert the url into the table yet. I would think it would be something like this:

```
stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO urls VALUES ('"+urlID+"','"+url+"')");
```

But how do I overwrite the urlID and url variables with the new urls each loop iteration?
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to update the same row multiple times? Or create new rows for each link?

You could just be using NextURLID instead of urlID (which isn't even initialized) for the value you want to insert. 

I am confused as to what you mean by "how do I overwrite the urlID and url variables with the new urls each loop iteration?" What exactly are you trying to overwrite? The row in the database? The local variables?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear enough! I am trying to look at a url, and then take all the links from that url and put them into a table. Each new link that is being inserted into the table should be on a new row.

Answer (score 1):

In your case a PreparementStatement is more appropriate:

```
String insertURL = "INSERT INTO urls(urlID, url) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertURL);

for (Element link : links) {
     ps.setInt(1, NextURLID);
     ps.setInt(2, link.attr("abs:href"));  
     ps.executeUpdate();

     NextURLID++;
}

// ...
```

Comment: im searchin for another answer but  your answer seems useful for me thanx alex